# How can I clone one computer's anaconda environment to another computer's anaconda

Tags: anaconda, conda

As the title said, I want to copy my desktop's environment quickly to my server computer. But the only method I found is cloning one environment in one computer.

Comment: What do you mean by _quickly_ ? Is recreating the environment from a list of packages too slow?

Comment: I wanna copy the environment's packages, well I know I can use docker to do this!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?